# Простой вопрос из php , запись файла

Tags: php

Что не так ?

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt". "r+") or die
    ("Создать файл неудалось");
$text = "Трэвис ";
fwrite($fh.$text) or die ("Сбой записи файла");
$line = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
echo $line;
?>
```

Этот код я попытался модернизировать из книжки, но уже есть большие сомнения на освоение этого замечательного языка.Как и ранние я воспроизводил всё полученное на xampe и если удавалось записывал в отдельную тетрадку. 
Какую книгу мне стоит прочитать если есть более упрощённые и модернизированные варианты кода.

Answer (score 0):

Запятые! Не точки:

```
$fh = fopen("testfile.txt", "r+") or die ("Создать файл неудалось");
$text = "Трэвис ";
fwrite($fh, $text) or die ("Сбой записи файла");
$line = fgets($fh);
fclose($fh);
 echo $line;
```

Имхо, книжка древняя - сейчас можно писать файл одной строчкой:

```
$text = "Трэвис ";
file_put_contents("testfile.txt", $text);
```

Comment: К какой книге мне лучше всего приложиться ?

Comment: @GermanBobrov к любой, которая описывает PHP как ООП язык. Во всех остальных случаях пользуйтесь [официальным](http://php.net/manual/ru/) справочником с примерами.

Comment: @GermanBobrov я бы поискал книгу с PHP7 в названии, где уже современный синтаксис и информация. Ну и отчаяно плюсую за знание и главное понимание ООП (пригодиться практически для любого языка). Не столь важно вызубрить все функции (всегда можно посмотреть в справочнике), сколько выстраивать хорошую логику в коде.